# Why if statement is executing while statement is false

Tags: python, simulation

Below this code if statement is executing and printing busy text when my frm and to value is not in in_line list. This a telephony system simulation problem.

I want that it will go to else statement when the value of frm and to not in in_line

```
call_list =[ 
         [1,    4,      38,     1050],
         [3,    5,      50,     1090]]



call_in_progress = [
         [1,    3,   1055],
         [2,   6,   1099]]



in_line = [1,3,2,6]

   while(len(call_in_progress)!=0):
        while(len(call_list)!=0):

    next_call = call_list[0]
    print("next call : ",next_call)
    Arrtival_time = next_call[3]

    frm,to = next_call[0],next_call[1]
    print(frm,to)
    print(in_line)
    if( frm or to in in_line ):

        print("busy")

        if(next_call[0] in in_line ):
            m_index = in_line.index(next_call[0])

            in_line.pop(m_index+1)
            in_line.remove(next_call[0])
            print(in_line)

        call_list.pop(0)
    else:
        np = [next_call[0],next_call[1],next_call[2]+next_call[3]]
        call_in_progress.append(np)
        call_list.pop(0)

   # print("prog ",call_in_progress)
    print("Completed ",call_in_progress.pop(0))
```

Comment: `from or to in line` means `(from) or (to in line)`, not `(from in line) or (to in line)`.

Comment: You also have severe indentation issues.

Comment: I'm not sure, because your code has gotten its indentation mangled, which is catastrophic in Python -- but I _think_ what you want is `if frm in in_line or to in in_line`.

Comment: actually, indention occurs when I paste it here. thanks for your advice , let me try

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations is tripping you up.

You currently have `frm or to in line`. But `in` is an operator, and `or` is a conjunction, and operators always come before conjunctions. So this gets interpreted as `(frm) or (to in line)`.

Since `frm` is non-empty, it's treated as `True`, and the condition as a whole becomes true.

You want something like `frm in line or to in line` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, and in many other languages, the branching conditional test, such as is the case for if statements, requires the condition to be a statement (which can be a single expression). If multiple conditions need to be met, each condition is typically required to be a separate statement.

So in the case, such as you have presented where you want ensure that the `frm` and `to` items belong to the collection, each condition needs to be tested separately.  To put it another way, the collection has to be tested against twice.

```
if to in in_line or frm in in_line:
    print("busy")
```

An easy way is to break down your tests into seperate if statements for each item you want to test.  The preceding code would be the same as writing:

```
if to in in_line:
    print("busy")

if frm in in_line:
    print("busy")
```

For an `AND` conditional:

```
if to in in_inline:
    if frm in in_inline:
        print("busy")
```

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) indicated with their comment, the way the test is currently written first checks to see if `frm` is a truthy value and then checks to see if the `to` item is in the collection `in_line`.